# How to store variables that can be accessed by all Spouts and Bolts in Apache Storm?

Tags: java, redis, apache-storm, jedis

I have a Storm topology that creates many Spouts and Bolts. They will obviously be spread out on various systems/nodes which have their own JVM's.

I understand that Storm will automatically manage the network communications so that the tuples emitted by the Spout will reach the Bolts on a different JVM.

What I don't understand is about how I can maintain a few variables that can keep track of things.
I want one variable that counts the number of tuples that have been processed by all instances of `Bolt-A`. Another variable for counting for `Bolt-B` and so on.

I also need a variable that acts as a flag so that I'll know when the Spouts have no more data to emit, so that the Bolts can start writing to SQL.

I considered using `Redis`, but wanted to know if that is the best way or is there any other way? Any code samples available anywhere? I Google-searched, but couldn't find much useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no way to share the variable between tasks on Storm.

Instead of directly sharing the flag, you can define your own 'control' message and send it to Bolts to know there're no message for Spout to emit.

Sharing state with Redis is one of possible options (you need to implement your own logic), but flag value could be flickering so you may want to take care of it.

Comment: If there is a static variable of a class reference by one of the bolt (Task), will the static variables value be available between each new tuple we process through this bolt.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the number of tuples emitted and transferred per component and also per instance of each component from the Storm UI. There is even a [REST API](http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/STORM-UI-REST-API.html) to retrieve the values.

Comment: Ok, but in this case there is no way for me to know how many tuples is enough. As mentioned in the question, I need a flag variable which the bolts can check.

Answer (score 0):

For the fist requirement you can may use Metrics API (http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.1/Metrics.html)

For the second requirement, why not send a "flush" tuple similar to the timer tuple?

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that for the second requirement, there's another way to create the topology structure: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2016/05/more-concepts-of-apache-storm-you-need.html#morecreativetopologystructures

Comment: Looks good. But it complicates topology meaning that all bolts must attach to separate stream and branch logic based on the stream name. I guess the approach is similar to the Time tuple. One point to add, when you say **nothingMoreToProcess** you should look at **allAcked**